# Combined multiply divide operation on 64bit signed integer without overflow

Tags: c, algorithm, biginteger, division, bignum

I need to calculate

```
result = (dividend * factor) / divisor
```

where

```
dividend: full range of int64_t values
factor: either a full range of uint32_t values or as a special case 2^32
divisor: positive values of int64_t
result: is guaranteed to fit in a int32_t
```

I need to do this in plain C/C++ without any libraries on a microcontroller.
The compiler supports int64_t and uint64_t types; most likely no hardware implementation for multiply or divide.
Currently I have a workaround for the uint32_t factor but I need a solution for factor 2^32.

Comment: What architecture are you going to run this on?

Comment: What _type_ is `factor`.  `int64_t`?

Comment: Type: for the special case it's a constant 2^32; otherwise it's uint32_t

Comment: For the special case of `2**32` use a shift, but if you have no hardware implementation for multiply or divide it's unlikely that a 64-bit overflow can be handled.

Comment: Architecture: It's a Tensilica core in a ESP8266 chip.

Comment: (pretty vanilla 32 bit "RISC", 32/32 giving 32bit quotient or remainder signed&unsigned, but not even 64/32→32bit quotient?)

Comment: If you "have a workaround" for 32-bit `factor`, for `2**32` can you tolerate using `2**31` and either doubling the dividend or halving the divisor?

Comment: (Please share your `workaround for the uint32_t factor`.)

Comment: There is no language C/C++. If you think different provide a link to the specification. I'll happily add a new tag.

Comment: And `result = (dividend / divisor) * factor`? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: `result = (int32_t)((dividend / divisor) * factor + ((dividend % divisor) * factor) / divisor);`? (Can the OP please include the assembly generated for the existing work-around?)

Answer (score 1):

> OP: "Currently I have a workaround for the uint32_t factor"

The `factor == 2^32` is a corner case and is all that is needed to be solved here as OP's "workaround" can handle factors `[0 ... 2^32-1]`.

If the `dividend` can be doubled without overflow, simple use `factor == 2^31` with a doubled  `dividend`.

If the `divisor` is even, use `factor == 2^31` with a halved `divisor`.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498844/combined-multiply-divide-operation-on-64bit-signed-integer-without-overflow/34501670#comment56739985_34498844)

Else the `dividend` is large.  Recall that the quotient is in `[-2^31 ... 2^31-1]` range.  In general, the product of the large `dividend` and `factor == 2^32` dividend by the `divisor` will out of the `int32_t` range, so those out-of-range combinations are not of concern as "result: is guaranteed to fit in a `int32_t`".

The acceptable edge conditions occur with a final quotient near the edge of the `int32_t` range.

```
 pow(2,63) == 9223372036854775808
 pow(2,62) == 4611686018427387904
 pow(2,32) == 4294967296
 pow(2,31) == 2147483648

 Smallest Dividends   Factor      Largest Divisors       Smallest Quotients 
-4611686018427387905  4294967296  -9223372036854775807   2147483648.00+
-4611686018427387905  4294967296   9223372036854775807  -2147483648.00+  OK
 4611686018427387904  4294967296  -9223372036854775807  -2147483648.00+  OK
 4611686018427387904  4294967296   9223372036854775807   2147483648.00+
```

After testing, `dividend` and `divisor`, the only representable answer in `INT32_MIN`.

---

Sample Code:

```
int32_t muldiv64(int64_t dividend, uint64_t factor, int64_t divisor) {
  if (factor >= 0x100000000) {
    assert(factor == 0x100000000);
    factor /= 2;
    if (dividend >= INT64_MIN/2 && dividend <= INT64_MAX/2) {
      dividend *= 2;
    } else if (divisor %2 == 0) {
      divisor /= 2;
    } else {
      return INT32_MIN;
    }
  }
  return  workaround_for_the_uint32_t_factor(dividend, factor, divisor);
}
```

The original problem is to detect this edge condition and how to handle it.. The  `workaround_for_the_uint32_t_factor()` may not have been coded yet, thus it was not posted.